# How to insert a row in mysql before union?

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have the following:

```
CREATE TABLE newtable AS (
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 as rownum, name, age FROM (
    SELECT name, age FROM clubAmembers
    UNION
    SELECT name, age FROM clubBmembers
)
) AS atable
```

How can I make it such that I can "stick in a new row at the beginning of the table" prior to the SELECT union such that it would start with:

```
rownum | name| age
1 | "Jordan" | 6  <-- This is an arbitrarily inserted record with name="Jordan" age="6" that is not a part of any of the clubAmembers or clubBmembers table.
```

The rest of the table (rownum 2 and onwards) would contain the actual result form the union with clubAmembers then clubBmembers.

Basically I am looking for:
CREATE TABLE
INSERT a row "Jordan" | 6
Perform select with union such that the rows after the first would start with "rownum=2", all the data from clubAmembers, etc.

How to best do this?

Comment: Order can only be reliably established with an ORDER BY clause. This is because most SQL, including UNION, is "set based".

Comment: the SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 establishes order if I am just unioning clubAmembers and clubBmembers (as in numbered 1 to ... n number of members). If its not possible for me to insert a single row before those tables are unioned while preserving order from rownum, what is the best alternative to accomplish what I want?

Comment: It does not establish the order of elements resulting from the *inside* union: the select operation occurs later. It might work as expected. Or it might not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"At the beginning of the table" is not truly meaningful to relational databases because the order results are returned are not guaranteed until you use an `ORDER BY` clause, at which point the order on disk becomes a moot point anyway.

In your case, since you want to guarantee an order in your result clause (and therefore ordering `@rownum`, you will have to use `ORDER BY`. Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE newtable AS (
    SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 as rownum, name, age 
    FROM (
        SELECT 'Jordan' AS name, 6 AS age, 0 AS ord
        UNION
        SELECT name, age, 1 AS ord FROM clubAmembers
        UNION
        SELECT name, age, 1 AS ord FROM clubBmembers
        ORDER BY ord
    )
) AS atable
```

Note that at no point does this guarantee that rows in `clubAmembers` will have a lower `rownum` than rows in `clubBmembers`. If you want to guarantee that `clubAmembers` have a lower `rownum`, while keeping the semantics of `UNION` (versus `UNION ALL`), you can use the following:

```
CREATE TABLE newtable AS (
    SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 as rownum, name, age 
    FROM (
        SELECT 'Jordan' AS name, 6 AS age, 0 AS ord
        UNION ALL
        SELECT name, age, 1 AS ord FROM clubAmembers
        UNION ALL
        SELECT name, age, 2 AS ord FROM clubBmembers AS b
        WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM clubAmembers AS a 
                         WHERE a.name = b.name AND a.age = b.age)
        ORDER BY ord
    )
) AS atable
```

Note if {`name`, `age`} could be duplicated within the `clubXmembers` table, you will need to add `DISTINCT`:

```
...
SELECT DISTINCT name, age, 1 AS ord FROM clubAmembers
UNION ALL
...
```

---

As per the request in the comments, if you had a `clubCmembers` table, you would do:

```
CREATE TABLE newtable AS (
    SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 as rownum, name, age 
    FROM (
        SELECT 'Jordan' AS name, 6 AS age, 0 AS ord
        UNION ALL
        SELECT name, age, 1 AS ord FROM clubAmembers
        UNION ALL
        SELECT name, age, 2 AS ord FROM clubBmembers AS b
        WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM clubAmembers AS a 
                         WHERE a.name = b.name AND a.age = b.age)
        SELECT name, age, 3 AS ord FROM clubCmembers AS c
        WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM clubAmembers AS a 
                         WHERE a.name = c.name AND a.age = c.age)
        AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM clubBmembers AS b
                       WHERE b.name = c.name AND b.age = c.age)
        ORDER BY ord
    )
) AS atable
```

Comment: What is the purpose of ord? Does this mean that if I set ord to be "2" for the SELECT on clubBmembers I can guarantee that rows in clubAmembers will have a lower rownum than rows in clubBmembers?

Comment: @SeiSeiei `ord` establishes an ordering in that your "Jordan" row comes first (`ord = 0`). If you want clubAmembers to come first, you can set ord to be `2` for clubBmembers, but the meaning of `UNION` (as opposed to `UNION ALL` will be lost. I will edit to explain.

Comment: I don't get the whole ordering thing. if you don't order at all everything will be inserted in the same order. no?

Comment: @user1988148 With `UNION ALL` that *should* be true, yes (although I do not know even this is 100%). However `UNION` is a set operation which removes duplicates, therefore there really is no guarantee which order the results are returned in.

Comment: So having a different value for "ord" breaks UNION unless you perform the extra WHERE NOT EXISTS check. Could you possibly modify the example to include a potential case if there is a "clubCmembers" so I can make sure I get it? Also, assuming the clubBmembers may have repeat names/ages within itself, but the same name/age pair wouldnt show up in clubAmembers or clubCmembers, is it still necessary to use the "WHERE NOT EXISTS" clause?

Comment: 1) Having a different value for "ord" breaks UNION: Yes. 2) Adding a `clubCmembers` will complicate the query a bit but sure I can add it. 3) If you want to remove repeat names within each table, but don't care about the result, you can use `UNION ALL` but would need a `DISTINCT` in each `SELECT`. Sorry I thought name and age would be unique in each table, but someone might be a member of two clubs, so I did not include the `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I got it right. But why don't you just add another union like this:

```
CREATE TABLE newtable AS (
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 as rownum, name, age FROM (
    SELECT 1, "Jordan", 6
    UNION ALL
    SELECT name, age FROM clubAmembers
    UNION ALL
    SELECT name, age FROM clubBmembers
)
) AS atable
```

Comment: I thjink the OP wants to insert the mentioned record (the one with Jordan) in the first position inthe new table then put the rest from the subquery.

Comment: I think the query I wrote will result in the same thing as yours. don't you think?

Comment: Your right, sorry i didnt see the line with the 1st record. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the create table statmenet from the insert statmenet:

1. Create the table (you must know which colums are gona be there)
2. Insert your 1st record `(INSERT INTO .... Values(...)`)
3. Use your statement but with insert into instead of create table like: `INSERT INTO YourNewTable.... Values(YourSubQuery)` (Nr and tye of columns must match your subquery)

Comment: Sample query please. If possible, want to know performance/speed versus other solutions (i.e. ORDER BY)

Answer (score 0):

This should do, I believe:

```
CREATE TABLE newtable AS (
  SELECT (@rownum:=IFNULL(@rownum,0)+1)+1 as rownum, name, age FROM (
    SELECT name, age FROM clubAmembers
    UNION
    SELECT name, age FROM clubBmembers
  ) AS s
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'Jordan', 6
) AS atable
```

Demo at SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab825/6